# How to use a dynamic set of conditions/queries stored in a column using pySpark in a when clause

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to derive a success criteria using a list of conditions stored in a yaml file and pyspark for processing, but in the process I'm unable to convert the column data to a valid string for using in the when clause of spark sql. I have the criteria as following

```
conds = '''
Name:
  criteria_1:
    column_1 = 'A' and
    column_2 = 'AA' and
    column_3 = 'AAA' and
    column_2 != column_3 and
    column_1 - column_2 <= n

  criteria_2:
    column_1 = 'B' and
    column_2 = 'BB' and
    column_3 = 'BBB'

'''
```

To access the rules, I have a python function as below

```
def get_criteria(criteria):
    conds = yaml.load(conds)
    try:
        cons = yaml["Name"][criteria]
        return cons
    except Exception as e:
        pass
    return None

spark.udf.register("extract_conditions", get_criteria, StringType())

df = spark.table("table")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
spark.sql("select extract_conditions(df.criteria) as cds, (case when \
           (extract_conditions(df.criteria)) then 'Ok' \
           else 'Reject' end) \
           as outcome from df").show(1,False)
```

The above doesn't seem to be using the result returned from the extract_conditions as a string and is throwing the below error

```
[DATATYPE_MISMATCH.UNEXPECTED_INPUT_TYPE] Cannot resolve "CASE WHEN extract_conditions(criteria) THEN Ok ELSE Reject END" due to data type mismatch: Parameter 1 requires the "BOOLEAN" type, however "extract_conditions(criteria)" has the type "STRING".; line 1 pos 7;
```

If I pass the when condition as a string as follows, it works as expected, but I need to pass these values dynamically based on the criteria column. Sample of hardcoded query:

```
spark.sql("select extract_conditions(df.criteria) as cds, (case when \
           (column_1 = 'A' and column_2 = 'AA' and column_3 = 'AAA') then 'Ok' \
           else 'Reject' end) \
           as outcome from df").show(1,False)
+-------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|cds                                                    |outcome|
+-------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|column_1 = 'A' and column_2 = 'AA' and column_3 = 'AAA'|Ok     |
|column_1 = 'A' and column_2 = 'AA' and column_3 = 'AAA'|Ok     |
+-------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Any pointers or suggestions are much appreciated.
Sample data:

```
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|criteria  |column_1|column_2|column_3|
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
|criteria_1|A       |AA      |AAA     |
|criteria_2|B       |BB      |BBB     |
+----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Solutions tried but failed:

1. using eval and string conversions
2. adding a dictionary to hold the string of conditions and based on the criteria column use the value from the dictionary

Comment: Do the conditions have to be inside a df? What is stopping you from implementing your conditions via a `for` loop in python ?

Comment: I'm open for suggestions and changes, the only expectation is the end result of the criteria to be in a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering indicates a data type mismatch in the CASE WHEN expression of your spark.sql statement. The extract_conditions UDF is returning a string type, but the CASE WHEN expression expects a boolean type.

To resolve this issue, you can modify your get_criteria function to return a boolean instead of a string. Here's an updated version of the code:

```
import yaml
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

# YAML conditions
  conds = '''
  Name:
      criteria_1:
          column_1: 'A'
          column_2: 'AA'
          column_3: 'AAA'
      criteria_2:
          column_1: 'B'
          column_2: 'BB'
          column_3: 'BBB'
   '''

    def get_criteria(criteria, column_1, column_2, column_3):
        conds_yaml = yaml.load(conds, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        try:
            conditions = conds_yaml["Name"][criteria]
             return (
                    column_1 == conditions['column_1'] and
                    column_2 == conditions['column_2'] and
                    column_3 == conditions['column_3']
      )
   except Exception as e:
      pass
   return False

   # Register UDF
   spark.udf.register("extract_conditions", get_criteria, BooleanType())

 # Sample data
 data = [["criteria_1", "A", "AA", "AAA"], ["criteria_2", "B", "BB", "BBB"]]
 df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF("criteria", "column_1", "column_2", "column_3")

     # Create temporary view
     df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

     # Run Spark SQL
     spark.sql("""
SELECT 
    extract_conditions(df.criteria, df.column_1, df.column_2, df.column_3) AS cds,
    CASE WHEN extract_conditions(df.criteria, df.column_1, df.column_2, df.column_3)
         THEN 'Ok'
         ELSE 'Reject'
    END AS outcome
FROM df
    """).show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try to implement it. There is a challenge though there are a few conditions where I don't compare them against a value but instead a column too, I've updated my yaml accordingly.